# What does "channel" mean in the context of QCD?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, experimental-physics, terminology

I am familiar with the common use for "channel" in terms of particle physics (like Mandelstam variables). What confuses me is how it's used in the following paper on QCD:

C. A. Dominguez, "Quark masses in QCD: a progress report", [Mod. Phys. Lett. A **26** (2011) 691-710](https://doi.org/10.1142/S0217732311035614), arXiv:[1103.5864](https://arxiv.org/abs/1103.5864).

To be specific, I quote several sentences from the aforementioned paper that uses the term "channel":

- "... the availability of experimental data in the **vector channel**, and the use of suitable ..."
- "... hence once determined in **some channel** these condensates can be used
  throughout."
- "... from the standard FESR in the **axial-vector channel** ..."

Where these quotes can be found on pages 1,5 and 7 respectfully.

I don't understand the context and how "channel" is used in these cases. A broad explanation would seriously be useful to me.

Answer (score 0):

This means a representation under Lorentz group. The hadrons, mesons and baryons, form different representations - for instance $\pi^0$ is pseudoscalar, and $\rho$-meson is a vector. By vector channel they mean the properties, pertitent to those mesons.

And the axial-vector means that this vector is axial vector, like $\gamma^{\mu} \gamma^5$.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer my question. This was extremely helpful. 

If you don't mind me clarifying my understanding with you, "channel" refers to a particular representation of the Lorentz group; these representations have particular properties such as being a vector, pseudoscalar, etc. These properties form categories, or channels, in which particles fall into.

Did I get that right?